# How can I fix my ajax parser so it shows all nodes that I want displayed

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I have been trying to work this xml data into divs I have managed it to a point but it will only show the first value not sure why and any help would be greatly aprrecated

I have followed a few tutorials to extract data from an XML file but can't get it to show for then one value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Movies</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "movies.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).find('dates').each(function() {
                var movies = $(this).find('film').attr('name');
                var time = $(this).find('session').attr('time');

             $('.container').append( movies + ' <br> ' + time );

        })
    },
        error: function() {
            $('.container').text('Failed to get feed');
        }
    });

        </script>           

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

        </div>


    </body>
</html>         


<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Version 8.216 (Build 8216) -->
<!-- INTERNET FTP Sessions (Extended - Sort By Date) -->
<!-- Sessions for 3 February 2019-->

<ROOT guid="{E8AFA1E2-B92A-4590-8049-50EE083899B0}" versionNo="8216" releaseNo="45577" dateCreated="3 February 2019" timeCreated="12:16 pm" dateFrom="3 February 2019" dateTo="3 February 2019" >
<site siteNo="9200" siteName="Starlight Cinema Centre" timeFormat="h:mm am/pm" >
<movies>
<cinemas>
    <cinema cinemaNo="1" name="CINEMA 1" cinemaID="1" cinemaTypeNo="0" />
    <cinema cinemaNo="2" name="CINEMA 2" cinemaID="2" cinemaTypeNo="0" />
    <cinema cinemaNo="3" name="CINEMA 3" cinemaID="3" cinemaTypeNo="0" />
    <cinema cinemaNo="4" name="CINEMA 4" cinemaID="4" cinemaTypeNo="0" />
    <cinema cinemaNo="5" name="CINEMA 5" cinemaID="5" cinemaTypeNo="0" />
    <cinema cinemaNo="6" name="The Lounge" cinemaID="6" cinemaTypeNo="1" />
</cinemas>
<dates>
    <date  asInteger="20190203" asText="3 February 2019">
    <film filmNo="3326" name="AQUAMAN (LD)" duration="2 hrs 40 mins" rating="M" >
    <cinemaType cinemaTypeNo="0" name="Cinema" >
        <sessions  filmNo="3326">
        <session time="1:15 pm" cinemaNo="5" />
                <session time="6:40 pm" cinemaNo="5" />
        </sessions>
    </cinemaType>
    </film>
    <film filmNo="3337" name="DRAGON BALL SUPER: BROLY" duration="2 hrs" rating="PG" >
    <cinemaType cinemaTypeNo="0" name="Cinema" >
        <sessions  filmNo="3337">
        <session time="1:40 pm" cinemaNo="1" />
        <session time="6:40 pm" cinemaNo="5" />
        </sessions>
    </cinemaType>
    </film>
    <film filmNo="3334" name="GLASS (LD)" duration="2 hrs 25 mins" rating="M" >
    <cinemaType cinemaTypeNo="0" name="Cinema" >
        <sessions  filmNo="3334">
        <session time="11:00 am" cinemaNo="1" />
        <session time="6:20 pm" cinemaNo="3" />
        </sessions>
    </cinemaType>
    </film>
    </date>
</dates>
</movies>
</site>
</ROOT>
<!-- End File -->
```

Need it to show all movies and times but it is only showing one like 
it only showing 
AQUAMAN (LD) 
1:15 pm

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one `dates` element so your loop is only executing once. What you actually want to do is iterate on the `film` elements:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(data).find('film').each(function() {
        var movies = $(this).attr('name');
        var time = $(this).find('session').attr('time');
        $('.container').append( movies + ' <br> ' + time );
    })
},
```

If you want to display movies grouped by date, then you would need to have a nested loop, something like:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(data).find('date').each(function() {
        var date = $(this).attr('asText');
        $('.container').append(date + '<br>');
        $(this).find('film').each(function() {
            var movies = $(this).attr('name');
            $('.container').append( movies + ' <br> ' );
            $(this).find('session').each(function () {
                 var time = $(this).attr('time');
                 $('.container').append( time + ' <br> '  );
            })
        })
    })
},
```

Comment: That is an awesome help thank you the only issue now is that the time var is only running once per movie even tried giving time its own function but still the same problem

Comment: @JeremySmith see my edit, I think that should loop over your session times properly.

Comment: Thanks so much, nick I see that the grouped by date edit worked a treat. Thanks for helping a newbie :-)